# What is the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x_1^3 + x_2x_3^2)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> I am having some difficulty computing the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x_1^3 + x_2x_3^2)$.

Could anybody give me some suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb Q[x_1,x_2,x_3]\dots$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf Q[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is a regular ring of dimension $3$. As it is a finitely generated algebra over a field and $\;x_1^3+x_2x_3^2$ is a non-zero divisor, *Krull's Hauptidealsatz* ensures 
$$\dim\bigl(\mathbf Q[x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x_1^3+x_2x_3^2)\bigr)=\dim\mathbf Q[x_1,x_2,x_3] -1=2$$

Comment: I think you missed an important thing: the $\mathbb Q$-algebra of polynomials is an integral domain. Otherwise I don't know if you can use that dimension formula.

Comment: I didn't miss it. It is enough to have a non-zero divisor on a finitely generated algebra over a field (as far as I remember, this works because such algebras are catenary rings).

Comment: I reformulate my objection: in fact, you have to show that $\dim R/p=\dim R-\text{ht}(p)$ (where $p$ is a minimal prime over a non-zero divisor, so $\text{ht}(p)=1$), and this doesn't follow from catenarity and I'm not sure that this holds for finitely generated algebras over a field unless they are integral domains.

Comment: @user26857: This is proved in *Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra*, Ch. 8, *Dimension*; §2, no 4, Algebras of Finite Type over a Field, Corollary 2 of Theorem 3.

Comment: This is proved in many places, but always for finitely generated algebras over a field which are **integral domains**, and I think this is the main point of our discussion: do we need (for a finitely generated algebra over a field, say $R$) to assume that it is an integral domain in order to have $\dim R/(x)=\dim R-1$ for $x$ a non-zerodivisor or not?